# Load properties from a file in Spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am trying load a properties file in a web Spring project. The file is called foo.properties and is located in src/main/resources. The content of the file is

```
foo.Root=C:/xampp/htdocs
foo.Folder=foo
foo.Pets=pets
```

I add the following configuration to my application context file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />
```

Then, I write it into my controller and send to a ModelAndView:

```
@Value("${foo.Folder}")
protected String assetsFolder;
....
modelAndView.addObject("assetsFolder", this.assetsFolder);
```

But, when I try display in my JSP model with `${assetsFolder}`, the final HTML show is `${foo.Folder}`. It should show the string "foo". What is bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I can resolve my problem, partially...

I erased

```
modelAndView.addObject("assetsFolder", this.assetsFolder);
```

Then, I add in my jsp page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
....
<fmt:bundle basename="foo">
    <fmt:message key="foo.Folder" />
</fmt:bundle>
```

The property is displayed correctly

But in the Controller, I try put it in a controller, I get `${foo.Folder}` value

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have your `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:foo.properties" />` in spring mvc configuration XML as well